# Convert nested json array to java Array

Tags: java, android, json

I have a json Array posted below i want to convert the json array to java class Type array or android so that i get all the element from the array in java including "doses" array please help me. just make java array.

```
   [  
   {  
      "_id":"58299a0ae1053c391fb95026",
      "legacy_ID":3014545,
      "name":"OLMESAN 20 MG TAB",
      "code":"OLMESAN.",
      "default_sales_price":8,
      "default_purchase_price":6,
      "box_quantity":30,
      "foreign":false,
      "__v":0,
      "creation_info":{  
         "creation_time":"2016-11-14T11:03:38.413Z"
      },
      "item_type":[  
         {  
            "sub_item_type_no":"4",
            "name":"TABLET",
            "legacy_ID":"1061",
            "creation_info":{  
               "creation_time":"2016-11-14T05:45:12.548Z"
            },
            "_id":"58294f68c08d0b186e467d9f",
            "__v":"0"
         }
      ],
      "route":[  
         {  
            "name":"ORAL",
            "legacy_ID":"1001",
            "creation_info":{  
               "creation_time":"2016-11-09T12:08:15.472Z"
            },
            "active":"true",
            "_id":"582311af5da26741ab82a00f",
            "__v":"0"
         }
      ],
      "manufacturer":[  
         {  
            "other_name":"Beximco Pharma",
            "name":"BEXIMCO PHARMACEUTICALS LTD",
            "legacy_ID":"3000018",
            "creation_info":{  
               "creation_time":"2016-11-12T08:41:39.229Z"
            },
            "active":"true",
            "_id":"5826d5c379520725a8e05350",
            "__v":"0"
         }
      ],
      "pack":null,
      "uom":[  
         {  
            "name":"PIECE",
            "legacy_ID":"10014",
            "creation_info":{  
               "creation_time":"2016-11-09T12:01:25.858Z"
            },
            "_id":"58231015f37a2140e437eeaa",
            "__v":"0"
         }
      ],
      "generic":null,
      "doses":[  
         {  
            "en":"1 tab at noon - (after meals) - to continue.",
            "bn":"১ বড়ি দুপুরে - (আহারের পর) - চলবে।",
            "is_default":true,
            "_id":"582815348bc48212898f63b8"
         }
      ]
   },
   {  
      "_id":"58299a0ae1053c391fb95026",
      "legacy_ID":3014545,
      "name":"OLMESAN 20 MG TAB",
      "code":"OLMESAN.",
      "default_sales_price":8,
      "default_purchase_price":6,
      "box_quantity":30,
      "foreign":false,
      "__v":0,
      "creation_info":{  
         "creation_time":"2016-11-14T11:03:38.413Z"
      },
      "item_type":[  
         {  
            "sub_item_type_no":"4",
            "name":"TABLET",
            "legacy_ID":"1061",
            "creation_info":{  
               "creation_time":"2016-11-14T05:45:12.548Z"
            },
            "_id":"58294f68c08d0b186e467d9f",
            "__v":"0"
         }
      ],
      "route":[  
         {  
            "name":"ORAL",
            "legacy_ID":"1001",
            "creation_info":{  
               "creation_time":"2016-11-09T12:08:15.472Z"
            },
            "active":"true",
            "_id":"582311af5da26741ab82a00f",
            "__v":"0"
         }
      ],
      "manufacturer":[  
         {  
            "other_name":"Beximco Pharma",
            "name":"BEXIMCO PHARMACEUTICALS LTD",
            "legacy_ID":"3000018",
            "creation_info":{  
               "creation_time":"2016-11-12T08:41:39.229Z"
            },
            "active":"true",
            "_id":"5826d5c379520725a8e05350",
            "__v":"0"
         }
      ],
      "pack":null,
      "uom":[  
         {  
            "name":"PIECE",
            "legacy_ID":"10014",
            "creation_info":{  
               "creation_time":"2016-11-09T12:01:25.858Z"
            },
            "_id":"58231015f37a2140e437eeaa",
            "__v":"0"
         }
      ],
      "generic":null
   }
]
```

Comment: why don't u use GSON?

Comment: use modal classes with arraylist and getter setters

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-to-parse-json-in-android)

Comment: using this link may help you creation pojo class
http://pojo.sodhanalibrary.com/Convert

Comment: using model class how it convert any example

Comment: how can i access "doses" array from the json Array

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();     
JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray)jsonObject; 
if (jsonArray != null) { 
   int len = jsonArray.length();
   for (int i=0;i<len;i++){ 
    list.add(jsonArray.get(i).toString());
   } 
}
```

Comment: how can i access doses Array from the jsson